# Print with PHP into Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, magento

Code for the analysis of the payment page but does not write the code in javascript codes..

For example (HTML Print):

---

```
<script>
woopra.track('Odeme Sayfasi', {
    urunSayisi: '',
    amount: '',
    currency: '$'
});
</script>
    21234.55
```

---

**2:** 2 pcs products

**1234.55:** amount

PHP & Javascript codes:

```
<?php 
$mageFilename = '/home4/emre2010/public_html/app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
umask(0);
Mage::app();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$output = "";
foreach ($session->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item) { ?>

<script>
woopra.track('Payment Page', {
    urunSayisi: '<?php $output .= $item->getQty(); ?>',
    amount: '<?php $output .= $item->getBaseCalculationPrice(); ?>',
    currency: '$'
});
</script>

<?php } print $output;  ?>
```

Why not write into the javascript code? - Where I make mistake?

*P.S: E-commerce script: Magento[1](http://magentocommerce.com/)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing 2 approaches. When you close the PHP tags and start your JavaScript code, that's getting output directly into the page. Then you're storing information in a variable instead of outputting it directly into the content.

You need to do something like this:

```
<script>
woopra.track('Payment Page', {
  urunSayisi: '<?php echo $item->GetQty(); ?>',
  amount: '<?php echo $item->getBaseCalculationPrice(); ?>',
  currency: '$'
});
</script>
```

If you want to build your JavaScript code and spit it out all in one go, then you'd need to put your JS code into a PHP variable and then print the output, like so:

```
<?php
$output = '';
$output .= "<script>";
$output .= "  woopra.track('PaymentPage', {";
$output .= "    urunSayisi: '" . $item->GetQty() . "',";
```

etc.

But the top approach of printing directly into your code is simpler and cleaner for what you seem to be doing.

Answer (score 2):

You're not printing the values where you think you are, just concatenating them into `$output`. I'd do it like this:

```
<?php 
$mageFilename = '/home4/emre2010/public_html/app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
umask(0);
Mage::app();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');

$output = "";
foreach ($session->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item) { 
    $qty = $item->getQty();
    $price = $item->getBaseCalculationPrice();
    $output .= $qty . $price;
    ?> 
    <script>
    woopra.track('Payment Page', {
        urunSayisi: '<?php print $qty ?>',
        amount: '<?php print $price ?>',
        currency: '$'
    });
    </script>

<?php 
}
print $output;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should `echo` or `print`

```
<script>
woopra.track('Payment Page', {
    urunSayisi: '<?=$item->getQty()?>',
    amount: '<?=$item->getBaseCalculationPrice()?>',
    currency: '$'
});
</script>
```

Comment: you will get an error if you do not have `short_open_tag` set to On in php.ini . it is the best practice not to write short hand. instead you should use <?php echo $blah; ?>

Comment: `Since PHP 5.4.0, <?= is always available.`